# xlwings with python 3.5 on Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-3.5, xlwings

I have been stuck for some time. My configuration is: `python 3.5`, `xlwings 0.5.0` and `Windows 7`. I get the following traceback while trying to `import xlwings`:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\xlwings\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from . import _xlwindows as xlplatform
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 15, in <module>
    import pywintypes
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 124, in <module>
    __import_pywin32_system_module__("pywintypes", globals())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 117, in __import_pywin32_system_module__
    assert sys.modules[modname] is not old_mod
AssertionError
```

After some search on the internet, my understanding is that the problem comes from pywin32 'known problems', but I am not sure what it is all about. Can you help, please?

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, your only easy option to install pywin32 on Python 3.5 is to use the [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) distribution. The [official binaries](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/) from sourceforge don't seem to work with Python 3.5. Also, there are no [unofficial binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pywin32) yet.

Comment: Hi Felix. Thanks for your reply. That is a bad news. I hope the guys at xlwings will fix that shortly. BTW what 'less easy' solutions are there?

Comment: I am that guy. But you should be talking to the guys behind `pywin32`, really. You could be compiling pywin32 from source, but I doubt it's going to lead you quicker to a solution. You could probably also just copy over all the relevant folders from an [Ana]conda installation (but unfortunately, that's a lot of files and folders). I wasn't successfull at `pip install conda` into the regular python.org installation, otherwise `pip install conda` and `conda install pywin32` would have been a possibility, too.

Comment: Feel free to contact me via email (on GitHub profile)

Answer (score 0):

I finally isntalled pywin32 from [here](https://bitbucket.org/zoomeranalytics/xlwings_examples/downloads), as suggested by Felix Zumstein. After a bit of cleaning in my Python 3.5 folders (`site-packages`), `xlwings` finally worked.