# python error when import (using xlwings lib)

Tags: python, pywin32, xlwings

Below is the error message when I import:

```
>>> from xlwings import workbook, range
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    from xlwings import workbook, range
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\xlwings\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from . import _xlwindows as xlplatform
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 10, in <module>
    import win32api
ImportError: No module named 'win32api'
```

I have tried Python 3.5 and 2.7.10 but both have no luck.

Comment: install `win32api` package. And then run the above..

Comment: @AvinashRaj, Package name is [`pywin32`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywin32), not `win32api`.

Comment: To install pywin32 with Python 3.5 on Windows, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/33769489/918626

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make sure you have win32api package installed. Install it using

```
pip install win32api
```

Comment: Package name is [`pywin32`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywin32), not `win32api`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `pywin32`.

```
pip install pywin32
```

Answer (score 0):

Please state which environment you using.Windows or Mac? It have dependency:

**Windows**

pywin32, comtypes

**Mac**

psutil, appscript

More, please refer xlwings README doc:

https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings