# Getting AssertionError message installing pip on windows 10

Tags: python

After having downloaded get-pip.py attempting to install, and opening cmd window in windows 10 I am getting the following error message when I type pip and hit enter:

```
    Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10240]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\adamh>pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\adamh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\adamh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\adamh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\adamh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "C:\Users\adamh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import pkg_resources
  File "C:\Users\adamh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import appdirs
  File "C:\Users\adamh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\appdirs.py", line 510, in <module>
    import win32com.shell
  File "C:\Users\adamh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\win32com\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    import pythoncom
  File "C:\Users\adamh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pythoncom.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pywintypes
  File "C:\Users\adamh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 124, in <module>
    __import_pywin32_system_module__("pywintypes", globals())
  File "C:\Users\adamh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 117, in __import_pywin32_system_module__
    assert sys.modules[modname] is not old_mod
AssertionError

C:\Users\adamh>
```

I tried all of the upgrades and such but none of them have been successful. Thank you very much for any help provided. Sincerely, will_learn

Comment: Might be dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/33769101/1072229 ?

Answer (score 0):

First Check if your python is running is properly from command prompt.

Open command prompt and run python it should show your python version else install it properly and add its path in environment variables

Mostly Pip should be already included in Python 2.7.9+ or 3.4+, but if for whatever reason it is not there, you can use the following one-liner.

Download https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py and run it with Administrator permission python get-pip.py (If you are on Linux, use sudo python get-pip.py)

You must to add pip's path into Environment Variables. Pip is contained in python's script directory.

Example my case: C:\Python35\Scripts\pip.exe

To add path to environment variables.

```
Hold Win and press Pause.
Click Advanced System Settings.
Click Environment Variables.
Add C:\Python35\Scripts (Sorry I don't know name of python 3.5's directory) to the Path on System variables.
Restart Command Prompt.
Edit
```

In another way, you can use pip-Win instead of pip. Read more here: https://sites.google.com/site/pydatalog/python/pip-for-windows

Comment: I tried to put pip.exe into environment variables again after locating using cmd window. Still no success installing pip-Win either, says failed to install setuptools. Please help

Comment: @will_learn I suggest you to completely remove your python and reinstall it once again and try to install python3.4+

Comment: I did, now it says: 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. However; the icon on the get-pip.py file changed afterwards for some reason.

Comment: I think the problem may be leftover pip_build directories. If you could help me to locate and delete them I would be very grateful. Sincerely Will_learn

Comment: Pip should be along with python..okay...Try to install pip through cmd...Python install pip

Comment: I fixed the problem by uninstalling all python, and reinstalling using python 3.6. Thanks for helping me to switch to a new computer via external hard drive. I would have done this earlier but didn't think it could possibly be that simple as I had success on another machine without such complications. I appreciate your assistance, sincerely Will_learn

Comment: Yeah glad to help you.

Comment: I had to switch to a new download of python 3.5.2 because 3.6 was unsupported. It left empty build and dist folders. Peace